# Video player with dual subtitles

Tags: windows, gratis, macos, video-player

I am looking for a media player to play videos with two subtitles at the same time (e.g. English and Spanish).

I'm using VLC, but this feature is [not there yet](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=98324), although there are some workarounds using a [Subtitler extension](https://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Subtitler+%28lite%29?content=152364) (as per this [post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=98324#p413487)).

However, I'd like to find a player with a native support for dual subtitles or with easy to install plugin.

Ideally free and cross-compatible with versions for Windows and macOS.

Comment: Here it is, it works for me I am using "MPC" https://www.raymond.cc/blog/playing-two-subtitles-at-the-same-time-in-dvd-player-and-computer/

Answer (score 3):

According to this [list](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/playing-two-subtitles-at-the-same-time-in-dvd-player-and-computer/), multiple subtitles are supported by the following players:

- **[Daum PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/)**

  > PotPlayer is from the same developer that’s responsible for creating KMPlayer who decided to leave that project and start another. Unsurprisingly PotPlayer also has a range of subtitle options like KMPlayer, including a subtitles browser and plenty of tweaking and display options. PotPlayer can show two subtitles on the video at the same time.
- [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/)

  > KMPlayer has been able to play more than one subtitle at once for quite a few years. Apart from that ability, it also boasts a number of options for displaying, loading and saving the subtitles back out again. Some of the other subtitle features are merging subtitles together, subtitle explorer/editor, syncing, multiple display and effect options, online subtitle finder and the ability to show up to three subtitles on screen at once.
- [Media Player Classic – Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.org/) with a Directshow filter called [VSFilter](http://nightly.mpc-hc.org/mpc-hc_apps/vsfilter/) or [xy-VSFilter](https://github.com/Cyberbeing/xy-VSFilter)

  > The disadvantage of MPC playing two subtitles at once is it can’t do it out of the box and requires you to do a few things first. Firstly, you need to install a Directshow filter called *VSFilter* and tick the box to configure it when the install is complete. In the Main tab tick Override placement and enter a vertical (V) number somewhere between 0-25 to put this subtitle at the top. *Click OK*. When you open a video file and want two subtitles, you can access the the bottom subtitle from the right click > Subtitles menu, the second subtitle is accessed via Filters > “VSFilter (auto-loading version)”, a green arrow icon in the system tray is also visible where you can right click and alter the top subtitle.
- [BS.Player](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/download.html)

  > BS.Player is one of a few media players that offer a paid version for Pro version updates. Thankfully the free version handles playing two subtitles at once with ease. A few options for uploading/downloading subtitles, timings and how they get displayed are available.

### macOS

Here is the list specific for macOS:

- [IINA](https://lhc70000.github.io/iina/) ([open-sourced](https://github.com/lhc70000/iina))

Comment: Thanks for IINA! Worked like a charm on my MacBook

Answer (score 3):

Beside KMP I've also used Media Player Classic with [ffdshow filter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/), which are both included in the K-lite codec pack. No other filters are needed

> ffdshow can be configured to display subtitles, to enable or disable various built-in codecs, to grab screenshots, to enable keyboard control, and to enhance movies with increased resolution, sharpness, and many other post-processing video filters. It has the ability to manipulate audio with effects like an equalizer, a Dolby decoder, reverb, Winamp DSP plugins, and more. Some of the postprocessing is borrowed from the MPlayer project and AviSynth filters
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffdshow

One subtitle will be displayed by MPC and the other is embedded in the video stream by ffdshow. In fact you can use any other players as long as ffdshow is used to decode

When ffdshow is decoding a video or audio, its icon will be shown in the notification area. Just right click it and enable *Subtitle*. You may need to open the configuration to select the appropriate subtitle file, or simply set different rules for MPC and ffdshow to load different subtitles

[image: ffdshow subtitle]

A downside of this is that the ffdshow-rendered subtitle quality will decrease if you zoom the video out, since it's embedded as images in the video stream. But so is the video's quality, so it's not a big problem

Feature-wise ffdshow is the best decoder I've ever used, with many useful filters like post-processing to increase the output quality significantly. However in the last few years the default filter has been changed to LAV filter. You can still use Codec Tweak Tool to change the default back to ffdshow if you want

Answer (score 1):

MPV worked for me to show multiple subtitle tracks on the same video screen on macOS (10.15.7), here's how I did it:

[image]

**Install HomeBrew by pasting this command into Terminal**

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

**Install MPV on macOS by running this command in Terminal**

`brew install cask mpv`

**Place .srt subtitle file in the same folder as your video file**

[image]

**Run this command in Terminal**

`mpv /users/myusername/movies/irony.mkv --sub-pos=30 -sid=1 -secondary-sid=2 -sub-scale=0.8 --sub-back-color=0.5/0.75`

`–sid=1`   is a bottom subtitle
`–secondary-sid=2`   is the top subtitle
`–sub-scale=0.8` is text size

`--sub-pos=30` positions both sub languages at the top of the screen

`--sub-back-color` sets bg color of subs and transparency in the format r/g/b/a where rgba are values 0-1

In my case, my `.srt` subtitle file contains Russian and English in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

From the links posted by @kenorb I found [submerge](https://submerge.ovh/).
Not a player, but a tool that merge 2 subs into one. Works fine with kodi or vlc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch films with two subtitles at the same time in android, use these players:

- MX Player
- Precise Frame mpv Video Player

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).